# Why does qiskit's density matrix output obscure the text, can it make this picture better?

Tags: qiskit

[image]
[image]

Obviously, the histogram here has covered the coordinate markers. Is there any way to make this state diagram look better?

Answer (score 1):

recommend using `plot_state_hinton` instead of `plot_state_city`, for better view of it.

I guess it is a bug or something that makes it look like that.
a related issue has already been reported:https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/3315

Comment: plot_state_hinton is a solution, but it cannot visually display the data. Maybe you have to think of a method to read the things in the plot_state_city function, and then draw the 3d model yourself

Comment: @R-XZhao sry, I don't understand what you mean draw the 3d model yourself, isn't that what plot_state_city is doing.

Comment: There is apparently a partial glitch in plot_state_city, I want to read out the individual amplitudes of the density matrix and plot it myself with matplot.